# Link Excel sheet to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, hyperlink

Is it possible to link an Excel sheet to a SQL Server database? I want to be able to join the Excel columns to the tables in SQL Server and run queries. I can find plenty of examples to link the tables from SQL Server to Excel, but I want the other way around.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: In other words, you want to use Excel to edit fields of an MS SQL Server table?

Comment: Hi Jason, No. I don't need to edit tables. for example I want to be able to dump 100 SKUs on the excel sheet and refresh a query to get cost price for those 100 SKUs from the SQL table.

Comment: Ok, see user3240704's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Set your worksheet as a [Data Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189667.aspx#Microsoft%20Excel)

> **Excel file path**
> Specify the path and file name for the spreadsheet
> from which to import the data. For example, C:\MyData.xlsx or
> \Sales\Database\Northwind.xlsx. Or, click Browse.
>
> **Browse**
> Locate the spreadsheet by using the Open dialog box.
>
> **Excel version** Select the version of Excel that is used by the source
> workbook.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a workable solution. I need to install 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 and try.

Comment: I use third part application "KNIME" to do any multi data source ETL stuff but that was the "correct" answer.